# Hard Integral [Heat Equation + Fourier Sine Series]

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series, closed-form

[image]

I encountered this integral while doing a heat equation problem in Advanced Calculus.

How does the person evaluate the integral involving

$$\int_0^\pi \sin x \cos (nx) \: dx $$

Can someone explain it to me in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may use the identity
$$
2\sin a \cos b =  \sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)
$$ to write, for $n \neq\pm1$,
$$
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\pi \sin x \cos (nx) \: dx &=\int_0^\pi \left(\sin( (1+n)x)+\sin( (1-n)x)\right) dx \\\\
&=\left[\frac {-\cos( (1+n)x)}{1+n}+ \frac {-\cos( (1-n)x)}{1-n}\right]_0^\pi\\\\
&=-\left(\frac {\cos( (1+n)\pi)}{1+n}+ \frac {\cos( (1-n)\pi)}{1-n}\right)+\left(\frac {1}{1+n}+ \frac {1}{1-n}\right)\\\\
&=\frac {(-1)^n}{n+1}-\frac {(-1)^n}{n-1}+\frac {1}{n+1}- \frac {1}{n-1}
\\\\
&=\frac {2(-1)^n}{n^2-1}+\frac {2}{n^2-1}
\end{align}
$$ giving

> $$
> \int_0^\pi \sin x \cos (nx) \: dx =\frac {(-1)^n}{n^2-1}+\frac {1}{n^2-1}, \qquad n \neq\pm1.$$

Comment: And if $n=\pm1$, we get that $$\int_0^\pi\sin x\cos(\pm x)\,\mathrm dx=0$$ Because of the identities $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\cos(x)=-\cos(\pi-x)$